# Spring boot jpa not generating spring security tables "users" and "authorities"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement basic JDBC authentication in my spring boot application using spring JPA and schema.sql to create tables on startup. I have a few other tables which are successfully getting generated on application startup. But "users" and "authorities" tables do not get created for some reason.

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authorities;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rx_patient;

#Basic Authentication
create table users
(
    username varchar(50)  not null
        primary key,
    password varchar(100) not null,
    enabled  tinyint(1)   not null
);

create table authorities
(
    username  varchar(50) not null,
    authority varchar(50) not null,
    constraint ix_auth_username
        unique (username, authority),
    constraint fk_authorities_users
        foreign key (username) references users (username)
);

create table rx_patient
(
    patient_id          varchar(50)  null,
    phone_number        varchar(20)  not null,
    patient_name        char(30)     null,
    facility            int          null,
    first_name          char(40)     null,
    last_name           char(40)     null,
    address             varchar(100) null,
    primary_email       varchar(30)  null,
    `preferred_ method` char(10)     null,
    dob                 varchar(20)  null,
    constraint rx_patient_phone_number_uindex
        unique (phone_number)
);

alter table rx_patient
    add primary key (phone_number);
```

> The rx_patient table gets generated successfully on startup but the other two tables do not.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    password: root
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rxascension
    username: root
    initialization-mode: always
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I am unable to figure out if I am missing some configuration or something. Thanks in advance.

*Console logs*

```
'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59191,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/honeybee/AscensionRx-Api/target/classes:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-server/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-config-server-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-client/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-config-client-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.11.2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.11.2/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.38/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/3.0.3/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.38/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.3.4.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.7.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.60/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.60/bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/5.1.3.201810200350-r/org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.54/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jzlib/1.1.1/jzlib-1.1.1.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/javaewah/JavaEWAH/1.1.6/JavaEWAH-1.1.6.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache/5.1.3.201810200350-r/org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.26/snakeyaml-1.26.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.11.2/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.13.3/log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.30/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.11.2/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.5.5/micrometer-core-1.5.5.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.12/HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.3.4.RELEASE/spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.3.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.3.4.RELEASE/spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.4.5/HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.21.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.24.0-GA/javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.14/byte-buddy-1.10.14.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.1.3.Final/jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3/dom4j-2.1.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.3/txw2-2.3.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.11/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/twilio/sdk/twilio/7.54.0/twilio-7.54.0.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-android/guava-29.0-android.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-compat-qual/2.5.5/checker-compat-qual-2.5.5.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.6/joda-time-2.10.6.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.11.2/jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson/0.11.2/jjwt-jackson-0.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl/0.11.2/jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.12/httpclient-4.5.12.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.2/jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.2/jackson-annotations-2.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.2/jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.48/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.12/lombok-1.18.12.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.10/commons-lang3-3.10.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/modelmapper/modelmapper/2.3.8/modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaikiranmathukumalli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar org.ascension.rx.dsrxapi.AscensionRxApiApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59191', transport: 'socket'
2020-11-28 12:57:49.340  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-11-28 12:57:49.488  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2020-11-28 12:57:49.610  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.r.dsrxapi.AscensionRxApiApplication  : The following profiles are active: local
2020-11-28 12:57:50.463  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-11-28 12:57:50.550  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 82ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-11-28 12:57:50.717  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=9f60a6c3-33da-3fbe-87ff-d85102167992
2020-11-28 12:57:50.824  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-11-28 12:57:51.097  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-11-28 12:57:51.103  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-28 12:57:51.103  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-11-28 12:57:51.178  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-28 12:57:51.178  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1557 ms
2020-11-28 12:57:51.452  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2020-11-28 12:57:51.679  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2020-11-28 12:57:51.839  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Nov 28 12:57:51 CST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2020-11-28 12:57:51.982  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-11-28 12:57:52.018  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2020-11-28 12:57:52.108  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-11-28 12:57:52.195  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2020-11-28 12:57:52.739  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-11-28 12:57:52.746  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-11-28 12:57:52.791  WARN 15029 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-11-28 12:57:52.892  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-11-28 12:57:52.893  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-11-28 12:57:53.399  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3064c0e2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@16c89c59, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@c372e3f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6a76f49b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@12ece543, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6fb0c833, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@886e2bb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@70c2ada7, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6d08056c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@54ad04ab, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@b6440dc]
2020-11-28 12:57:53.498  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-11-28 12:57:53.580  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-11-28 12:57:53.584  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-11-28 12:57:54.062  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-11-28 12:57:54.074  INFO 15029 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.r.dsrxapi.AscensionRxApiApplication  : Started AscensionRxApiApplication in 5.316 seconds (JVM running for 6.183)
2020-11-28 12:57:54.519  INFO 15029 --- [)-192.168.1.242] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-11-28 12:57:54.519  INFO 15029 --- [)-192.168.1.242] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-11-28 12:57:54.528  INFO 15029 --- [)-192.168.1.242] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms'
```

Comment: Sounds a little bit odd that one/some tables gets created. Can you please try to add `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`

Comment: I already have that in my application.yml file

Comment: This URL should cover your case: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-jdbc-authentication

Comment: Did you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have set ddl-auto: none in you application.yml file. Try changing it ot ddl-auto: 'create' and also enable show-sql.

Example:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: 'create'
    show-sql: true
```